# RAID 1 failed disk replacement - backup recommendations

Tags: backup, raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

Having recently lost one drive in a RAID1 (mirrored) setup with a "hot spare" on a HP ProLiant ML350 G6 server, we're about to have it replaced with a new one. The disks are hot swappable so for that part there should be no problems - you take out the bad one, put a new one in its place and the RAID array starts rebuilding itself automatically.

However one cannot be to safe, so we're looking for a backup solution to have the data backed up before we swap the disk (for some users this resulted with a total loss of data, from what we read). Since we have next to no experience with backing up off RAID discs, would anyone here have a recommendation on the backup procedure? What software to use? Shall we back up data only or create full disk images?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is it that you're just now thinking of data backups *AFTER* a disk failure? Also, this question is subjective and opinion based. What's the best method? The one that works for you and that meets your data protection needs.

Comment: We have a firm data backup policy in place, however the server in question runs several important VMs that we cannot afford to be offline for too long. The backup is just a precaution since we heard some people lost everything after hot-swapping a drive (ended up with a RAID 1 array of two blank discs) which we wish to avoid.

Comment: The backup is just a precaution? That makes it sound like an inconsequential after thought. RAID isn't backup. If those virtual machines and/or data is important to the business than having regular, reliable and tested backups should be paramount. The RAID is secondary to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't focus on the wrong thing!

You're safe to replace the disk without a backup... Hardware RAID 1 (2 disks) with a hot-spare (1 disk) means that the spare would have rebuilt from the healthy disk, bringing the array back into good health.

You can pull the failed disk and replace it with a new drive. It will rebuild and the spare will go back to hot-spare duties.

This is not a risky operation. However, in terms of your need for backups, it's important to understand that RAID is not backup. You should have a backup process in place. Suggestions on what specific software to use are beyond the scope of this question (*plus, you didn't indicate what operating system you're using*).

Comment: Sorry, you're right, i did forget to mention the OS - it's Citrix XenServer.

As i said in the other comment, we do have a firm data backup policy in place (weekly full backups, daily diff and hourly transaction log backups on all essential data, on and off site) but this is a different kettle of fish and something we're getting into for the first time. This particular box houses several important VMs that we cannot afford to have off line for too long.

We have heard some people suffered a total loss of all data (ended up with a blank RAID 1 array) and are just being cautious to avoid that.

Comment: Just to clarify - basically what i was asking for is if there is someone who faced the same situation before (it is the first time for us, i guess there will be lessons to learn from all of this) and was willing to share some advice how to best proceed. After giving it a bit of a thought i guess the above qualifies as an answer to that question.